# How to avoid electricity to pass through inverter output socket but output socket will always be connected to electric line?

Tags: ac, dc, inverter

please pardon me if I have written a duplicate question, but know that I am a novice.
I have a DC to AC Inverter which used to give me 220V 500W AC output. But when I connected the output side with the electric connection and when the connection expecting that it would automatically start to provide the electricity. But unfortunately the inverter got damaged due to connecting the output socket to the electric line while output socket was serving electricity.

What can I do to ensure that the inverter output port will always be connected with electric line, but the electricity will flow towards one direction only, fron the inverter to electric line?

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do to ensure that the inverter output port will always be connected with electric line, but the electricity will flow towards one direction only, from the inverter to electric line?

There is nothing you can do if the  inverter is not a grid-tie type.

- Your mains is AC which means current is alternating. You can't block current in one direction.
- A grid-tie inverter will track the mains frequency, voltage and phase and adjust the output to match. Your inverter probably doesn't have this feature so you can't  connect it to the mains.

There will be local regulations covering addition of inverters to the mains. You have to have permission to do this so that you don't kill someone working on the line when the power is supposed to be off.

Comment: so, does purchasing a grid-tie inverter solve my problem?

Comment: It solves part of the problem, in that you can connect the device to your mains AC supply, but it doesn’t solve the second part of the problem which is that if the mains power fails then your converter will try to provide power to your entire neighbourhood, which would be bad in a number of ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your such great insight. So, do you suggest me to have an additional switch for my electronic equipment which will be used to manually control when to let the inverter pass the electricity and when not to?

Comment: No. Add sockets to your inverter and plug specific devices into that so that they can run when the power is off. Do not try to feed your house with the inverter. You don't have enough technical knowledge and you don't have the right equipment.